# How to change the color of the success button with SASS?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, sass, bootstrap-4

Currently the success button of my theme is green. I want to put it in yellow. How can I do this ?

In the `_variables.scss` file there are these lines :

```
$btn-success-color:              $btn-default-color !default;
$btn-success-bg:                 $brand-success !default;
$btn-success-border:             $btn-success-bg !default;
```

I added the following lines to my custom file `style.scss` :

```
$btn-success-color:              #000 !default;
$btn-success-bg:                 #FFD700 !default;
$btn-success-border:             #FFD700 !default;
```

I don't know if it's the right method, but it doesn't work.

I have compiled my theme with the changes but the success button is always green.

Comment: Welcome to SO, it should work fine as per your code above here. But also the file sequencing (the sequence you import sass files) matter. So if you are declaring your updated variables after it is used by any other partials( other sass files) then it won't work as expected.

Comment: @divy3993 Here is my file and it seems correct to me, what do you think ? https://pastebin.com/iPeguVcJ The style appears well in the code of my site but it does not replace the default style https://ibb.co/jkY0bg0

Comment: Here I notice you have named a variable `$btn-success-color:` where bootstrap has it as `$brand-success:`.

Comment: So basically if you are trying to override the Bootstrap variable `$brand-success` so you have to have same name of your variable with updated value to override it. I am still not clear what you are trying if this is not what you want.

Comment: @divy3993 Ok thank you, I just saw my error, there was a custom stryle in my style.css file because it is a new theme that I am trying to convert to scss

Comment: @divy3993 Maybe you can help me because I have another problem that has bothered me for a very long time. I host the "Glyphicons Halflings" font locally as you can see in my file. But the theme continues to use the remote font. I don't understand why, because I think I did the right method.

Comment: oh okay. Sure let me know how can I help you.

Comment: @divy3993 Finally I succeeded, thanks anyway

Comment: glad you found what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to override the variables in your `style.scss`, you have to position them **before** importing `_variables.sccs`

According to Bootstrap :

> Variable overrides within the same Sass file can come before or after
>   the default variables. However, when overriding across Sass files,
>   your overrides must come before you import Bootstrap’s Sass files.

If you want to do this the clean way, I suggest you load default bootstrap variables first, and load your custom var form another file, for example `_variables-custom.scss` .

In `_variables-custom.scss`, you copy / paste the values from `_variables.scss` to override them. You have to remember several things :

1. `_variables-custom.scss` must be imported **after** the default `_variables.scss`
2. all the `!default` must be removed in you `_variables-custom.scss`, for them to correctly override the `_variables.scss` values.
3. I suggest, if possible, not to store any variables outside of `_variables-custom.scss` so when you search a var, you know where it is.

so you should have in you style.scss :

```
@import 'variables.scss'
@import 'variables-custom.scss'
```

_variables.scss :

```
$btn-success-color:              $btn-default-color !default;
$btn-success-bg:                 $brand-success !default;
$btn-success-border:             $btn-success-bg !default;
```

_variables-custom.scss :

```
$btn-success-color:              #000 ;
$btn-success-bg:                 #FFD700;
$btn-success-border:             $btn-success-bg;
```